# Create a stereo track from non-paired inputs e.g. channels 2 & 3

Tags: logic-pro, garage-band

GarageBand allows you to create stereo tracks but only seems to support stereo tracks as channels 1&2, 3&4, etc:

[image]

But my setup (Using BlackHole to create an Aggregate input) looks like this:

1. System Mic
2. USB Interface Channel 1 (guitar)
3. USB Interface Channel 2 (XML mic)
4. System output, Left (via Blackhole)
5. System output, Right (via Blackhole)

[image]

I want to record channels 2 & 3 as a stereo channel but this simply doesn't seem supported.

My question is if GB *does* allow me to create a stereo track from *any* 2 channels - and if not, does Logic?

Comment: Why not save each of them to stereo panned hard left and hard right and then mix them?

Comment: I am also wondering "why stereo," since they are not the same performance and the  idea is to record the tracks and bounce them. Recording in stereo may actually hinder your ability to place the individual mono sources into the stereo field. The easiest work-around is to move the system mic to 3 or 5.

Comment: @Yorik they specifically say the system mic has to be set as channel 1 for BlackHole to work

Comment: @PiedPiper I can but now if I want to change the volume of that stereo track I have to adjust two things - or can I mix/combine them into one stereo track right after recording?